# How do TrecTools library in Python produce evaluation results from evaluation metrices after passing two parameters as a file in TrecEval method?

Tags: python, join, merge, information-retrieval

**Hello everyone, I am facing below error while computing information retrieval evaluatiion metrics using trectools in Python. I am passing two files to TrecEval method (prediction[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L63oN.png), gold_labels[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tloGu.png)). In gold_labels file, first column is displaying tweet id's and third column
claim id's, and for prediction file, first column is again displaying tweet id's and third column is representing claim id's. As you may notice that claim id is different in prediction file, it's in integer format here. Is it causing the error? Could you please also explain how do trectools library compute evaluation metrices? not asking about how do evaluation metrices(Map@k, P@k) get computed but how this whole process work after givng the prediction and gold-lables file as parameters.**

**Error:**

File "evaluate.py", line 41, in extract_metrics
print(results.get_precision(1))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\trectools\trec_eval.py", line 670, in get_precision
merged = pd.merge(run[["query", "docid", "score"]], qrels[["query","docid","rel"]], how="left")
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 74, in merge
op = _MergeOperation(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 656, in **init**
self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1165, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

**Details about the Error:**

I am facing this error, ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns.

results = TrecEval(prediction, gold_labels)

results.get_metric(depth)

e.g. results.get_map(depth=1),

error is in this line. Maybe, it's due to the data that I am using, as data looks like this

prediction file

2019_bla_bla_bla(string format) Q0 4353(int format) 1 score lable

2020_bla_bla_bla(string format) Q0 9923(int format) 1 score lable

gold labels file

2019_bla_bla_bla1(string) 0 vclaim-pol-375(string)   1

2019_bla_bla_bla2(string) 0 vclaim-pol-16814(string) 1

Maybe trectools while joining in the backend not able to find similar data type for vclaim in both data files, so that's why it's giving this error. So just wanted to be sure that whether is there something wrong with the data, especially vclaim id in both files?

[tweet claim pairs file in TrecQrel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tloGu.png)

[tweet claim Prediction file in TrecRun format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L63oN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Trectools is open source. You can read the code yourself to understand what is going on behind the curtains (https://github.com/joaopalotti/trectools). I think this can be a good exercise for you.

If your goals is figuring out what is wrong with your code, please share as much as possible. Copy and paste the smallest snippet of your code that results in this error and also share the actual data that you are using. Dont share the data as an image, but copy and paste the it here as like this:

```
2019_bla_bla_bla1 0 vclaim 1
2019_bla_bla_bla2 0 vclaim 1
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please read the post again. I have updated the post and mentioned details about the error.

Comment: Your problem is that the document name changed. In the QRels file, document names are strings ("vclaim-pol-number"), while in the Run file they are integers (4353, 9923). Obviously, they do not match. To solve your problem, you should either strip the "vclaim-pol-" from the document name or add "vclaim-pol-" with something like: ```"vclaim-pol-%s" % docid.zfill(5)```.

Comment: Hi @UsamaMazhar, did you solve your problem?